# C++ will not create a file to output text to?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, io, output

So, what I have here is a simple snippet of C++ code that merely askes for a filepath, checks if the filepath exists, and if it does, the program closes. If it doesn't, it creates a file and writes text to it. The path I enter is C:\temp.txt, but no matter which path I use the result is the same: No file is created. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

```
string outFile = "";
cout << "Enter a file path for an output file that does not exist already: ";
cin >> outFile;
ofstream file_writer;
file_writer.open(outFile, ios::out);
if (file_writer.good()) {
    cout << "This file exists already!" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 255;
}
else
file_writer << "Hello";
file_writer.close();
```

Comment: If you go to C:\ yourself, and try to create a file called temp.txt, are you allowed to? Or do you have to pass a UAC prompt first?

Comment: @PaulR That is what I am doing, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: You've got your test backwards. If it's good, you can try writing to it; if *not* good, something bad has happened.

Comment: Note \\ is unnecessary and wrong. Escape backslashes *in your source code* not in the data.

Comment: @immibis I cannot create a txt file in C: However, it doesn't give me a UAC prompt, it merely doesn't have the option to create a txt file when I right-click.

Comment: @TheCatfishMaw Open Notepad, save as, type in C:\test.txt in the name box, try to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
string outFile = "";
cout << "Enter a file path for an output file that does not exist already: ";
cin >> outFile;
ofstream file_writer;
file_writer.open(outFile, ios::in);
if (file_writer.good()) { //This now just checks if the file exists already
    cout << "This file exists already!" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 255;
}
file_writer.open(outFile, ios::out); //Now since we know the file doesn't exist, we can create it safely
if (!file_writer.good()) {
    cout << "Failed to create file!" << endl;
    return 254;
}
file_writer << "Hello";
file_writer.close();
```

Comment: This works correctly. I'm not sure how and I'm in a hurry so I'll analyze it later, but it works perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nice! `ofstream::good()` returns true if no error occurs. Use a negation in the if-condition.

```
if (!file_writer.good()) {
...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it now writes to a file regardless of if it exists or not. I want to create a file and write to it if it's filename doesn't exist, and exit the program if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Check your fail() error message:

```
if (outfile.fail())
    cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
```

Comment: This has the same problem as @Niall's answer. The program will now write to the file whether it exists or not. I want it to only write to a file if it doesn't exist, creating it in the process.

Comment: You can open the file with ios_base::out | ios_base::in as param and then check with is_open() if the file exists.

Comment: This works a little better, since now it returns an error message if the file exists, and doesn't when the file doesn't exist. However, now it won't create the file at all.

Comment: How would I check that? I spoligize if that's a silly question, C++ is new to me.

Comment: if (outfile.fail())
    cout << strerror(errno) << endl;

Comment: If I use what you mention here, if the file does not exist, it is unable to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to "C:".
Try with a different path, and it should work.

Comment: Right, now I see. Writing to D: works, but the check to see if the file exists or not still doesn't. However, this is still a good step forward. It is at least creating the file now. Thank you.

Comment: `file_writer.good` checks for the bit error flags, so he will returns true if the file can be opened. Maybe you could add a check on the filesize.

Answer (score 0):

This response may be a little late, but I just spend two days figuring out why Visual Studio C++ was not creating any text files.

I'm going through Wrox Professional C++ Fourth Edition. In chapter 13 on the section for file streams, I could not get any examples to work. I spent many hours downloading sample code with the same results.

I then looked at my anti-virus software. There are two settings in there that caught my eye: Folder Access, and Exclusions. I'm running Windows Security on Widows 10. I changed Exclusions to prevent the security software from monitoring my vs2019 folder and subfolders. No improvement.

I then looked at the parent folder `c:\files`.  This had folder access enabled. I removed this and everything worked fine. Instead of putting folder access on the entire files folder, I enabled it on the specific subfolders omitting the vs2019 folder.  I hope this save somebody many frustrating hours.